# SQL Server 2017 how to limit the display of DB object list for Non Admins

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2017

In SQL Server 2012, non-admin users get to see only the tables / views they have access to (using SSMS or any other tool).

In SQL Server 2017, it doesn't work that way. It doesn't show them any objects or (when view any database checkbox is enabled), it shows all databases / tables / views to non-admin users (of course they can query only the objects they have access to).

Is there a way to restrict the display of objects which they have access in SQL Server 2017?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and here are the two statements.

```
   1. Revoke view any definition to usr_test

   2. grant  view any database  to usr_test
```

https://medium.com/@gchandra/implement-sql-server-2012-like-permissions-in-sql-server-2017-b607c4616124